# Finding function for capital interest

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Haven't fully grasped derivatives and I believe this question really holds the gist of it

Your bank account has a continuous capital interest rate of 7%.

The formula for this is

$$\frac{dB}{dt} = 0.07B$$

where B stands for balance.

I'm probably reading this wrong, but here's what I read: *The change in your balance over time is 0.07B*

Shouldn't there be a $t$ factor on the RHS? i.e. $$0.07Bt$$

Comment: why should there be? you will have a form of growth $~\mathrm{e}^{0.035t^2}$ which is not the continuous interest rate.

Comment: having written the answer, i clearly understand it does not give the right answer, i would now like to understand why @Chinny84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question.  The way you read it makes sense to me: *the change in $B$ over time is $0.07B$, or 7% of $B$.*

To see why there shouldn't be any explicit $t$ dependence in $\frac{dB}{dt}$, think about it this way: Suppose you and I have the same bank balance and same interest rate, but my account has been open for 10 years longer than yours.  Should we get the same interest payment, or should I get more?

> We should get the same interest payment, because the bank only cares how much money is in the account, not for how long it has been there.

The same is true for any growth-law differential equation.  Usually there isn't any dependence on $t$ because the system only depends on what's happening right now.

Comment: We should get the same? I actually don't know the answer to that question

Comment: @EricJohnson Interest is a portion of the balance only.  So yes, we should get the same interest.